# How would I include www or non-www in a redirect?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/forum\/" [R=301,L]
```

This is causes a redirect WITHOUT the www whether the www. is used or not.

However, I want it to use the www if its used, or if its not used, dont include it (for cookie reasons)

IE

```
http://mysite --> http://mysite  
http://www.mysite  --> http://www.mysite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable in the redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond ^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/forum/ [R=301,L]
```